# PHP file is not called from Ajax script

Tags: php, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "./create_file.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        name: name,
        phone: phone,
        email: email,
        message: message
    },
cache: false,
...
...
...
```

When above script is called, it is not running below script that is written inside create_file.php and thus not creating text file. Please let me know how to solve this issue.

```
$content = "test text";
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/1file.txt","wb");
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Do you have writable  permission on the folder ? @krahir2016

Comment: @AnkiiG, yes, i have write permission on the folder

Comment: Have you checked error logs? @krahir2016

Comment: @AnkiiG, how can i check error logs? please let me know

Comment: Which environment you are using?

Comment: @AnkiiG, PHP 5 & MySQL with IIS 7.5

Comment: @krahir2016: Kindly check what http response code you are getting when executing the ajax code. I doubt you're not getting 200 as response code. It will be 404

Comment: @Haridarshan, I am not getting any error code, I am just getting javascript success message after submitting form but still text file (.txt) is not created.

Comment: Regarding write permissions, does the web server have permission to write to the folder?  I'm not overly sure how permissions work with IIS though.

Comment: @krahir2016: As AnkiiG has mentioned, kindly check php error logs. You can find the php error log path in **php.ini** file. Most probably the path will **C:\Windows\temp\**

Comment: @Haridarshan, there is no permission issue in IIS or website. But I will check php error logs and get back to you. Thank you

Comment: try adding `success function` in your `ajax` function and alert the response like this :
`success: function(html)
                        {
                            alert(html);
                        }`
and use `echo $content; die;` in your **create_file.php** file

Comment: @Haridarshan, due to php error log I was able to find out php issue and now it is solved.So ty very much